# Sparksql get sample rows with where clause

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to get a sample n rows of a query with a where clause?

I tried to use the tablesample function below but I ended up only getting records in the first partition '2021-09-14.' P

select * from (select * from table where ts in ('2021-09-14', '2021-09-15')) tablesample (100 rows)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise Monotonically Increasing ID - [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#monotonically_increasing_id) or [Rand](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.rand.html) to generate an additional column which can be used to Order your dataset to generate the necessary sampling field

Both of these functions can be used in conjunction or individually

Further more you can use `LIMIT` clause to sample your required `N` records

**NOTE - orderBy would be a costly operation**

#### Data Preparation

```
input_str = """
1   2/12/2019   114 2
2   3/5/2019    116 1
3   3/3/2019    120 6
4   3/4/2019    321 10
6   6/5/2019    116 1
7   6/3/2019    116 1
8   10/1/2019   120 3
9   10/1/2019   120 3
10  10/1/2020   120 3
11  10/1/2020   120 3
12  10/1/2020   120 3
13  10/1/2022   120 3
14  10/1/2021   120 3
15  10/6/2019   120 3
""".split()

input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, input_str))

cols = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, "shipment_id  ship_date   customer_id quantity".split()))
            
n = len(input_values)

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+4]) for i in range(0,n,4)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, cols)

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('ship_date',F.to_date(F.col('ship_date'),'d/M/yyyy'))

sparkDF.show()

+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+
|shipment_id| ship_date|customer_id|quantity|
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+
|          1|2019-12-02|        114|       2|
|          2|2019-05-03|        116|       1|
|          3|2019-03-03|        120|       6|
|          4|2019-04-03|        321|      10|
|          6|2019-05-06|        116|       1|
|          7|2019-03-06|        116|       1|
|          8|2019-01-10|        120|       3|
|          9|2019-01-10|        120|       3|
|         10|2020-01-10|        120|       3|
|         11|2020-01-10|        120|       3|
|         12|2020-01-10|        120|       3|
|         13|2022-01-10|        120|       3|
|         14|2021-01-10|        120|       3|
|         15|2019-06-10|        120|       3|
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

#### Order By - Monotonically Increasing ID & Rand

```
sparkDF.createOrReplaceTempView("shipment_table")

sql.sql("""
SELECT
 *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *
        ,monotonically_increasing_id() as increasing_id
        ,RAND(10) as random_order
    FROM shipment_table
    WHERE ship_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    ORDER BY monotonically_increasing_id() DESC ,RAND(10) DESC
    LIMIT 5
)
""").show()

+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+-------------+-------------------+
|shipment_id| ship_date|customer_id|quantity|increasing_id|       random_order|
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+-------------+-------------------+
|         15|2019-06-10|        120|       3|   8589934593|0.11682250456449328|
|          9|2019-01-10|        120|       3|   8589934592|0.03422639313807285|
|          8|2019-01-10|        120|       3|            6| 0.8078688178371882|
|          7|2019-03-06|        116|       1|            5|0.36664222617947817|
|          6|2019-05-06|        116|       1|            4|    0.2093704977577|
+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+-------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to not use order by? 

May I use this 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-sampling.html

Comment: why do we need monotonically_increasing_id() if we are ordering by rand()?

Comment: Adding an additional field to uniformly sample the dataset

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Dataset` there is built-in functionality for this as outlined in the [documenation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#sample(withReplacement:Boolean,fraction:Double):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D):

```
sample(withReplacement: Boolean, fraction: Double): Dataset[T]

Returns a new Dataset by sampling a fraction of rows, using a random seed.

withReplacement: Sample with replacement or not.
fraction: Fraction of rows to generate, range [0.0, 1.0].

Since

    1.6.0
Note

    This is NOT guaranteed to provide exactly the fraction of the total count of the given Dataset.
```

To use this you'd filter your dataset against whatever criteria you're looking for, then sample the result. If you need an *exact* number of rows rather than a fraction you can follow the call to `sample` with `limit(n)` where `n` is the number of rows to return.

Comment: I'm using SparkSql, the equivalent functions are https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-sampling.html